# How to prevent a TikZ arrow from touching a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows

I am using TikZ to draw some trees in my thesis. This is a sample of what is being done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\newcommand{\Ta}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=30pt, sibling distance=90pt]
  \node {}
        child {node {$p(x)$}
        child{node {$skipped$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
    }
        child {node {$s(x)$}
        child {node {$\sim s(x)$}
            child{node {$closed$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
        }   
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\Tb}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=30pt, sibling distance=90pt]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=30pt, sibling distance=80pt]
  \node {}
        child {node {$p(x)$}
        child{node {$q(x)$}
            child{node {$skipped$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
        }
        child{node {$\sim p(x)$}
            child{node {$closed$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
        }
    }
        child {node {$s(x)$}
        child {node {$\sim s(x)$}
            child{node {$closed$} edge from parent[draw=none]}} 
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\newcommand{\Tc}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=30pt, sibling distance=90pt]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=90pt]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=80pt]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=40pt]
  \node {}
        child {node (n1) {$p(x)$}
        child{node {$q(x)$}
            child{node (n2) {$\sim p(x)$}
                child{node {$closed$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
            }
            child{node {$\sim q(x)$}
                child{node {$closed$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
            }
            child{node {$ r(x)$}
                child{node {$skipped$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
            }
        }
        child{node {$\sim p(x)$}
            child{node {$closed$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
        }
    }
        child {node {$s(x)$}
        child {node {$\sim s(x)$}
            child{node {$closed$} edge from parent[draw=none]}} 
    };

\path[dashed, <->](n1)edge [bend right=45]  node[above left]{reduction}(n2);

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\pgfversion

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering\Ta
\caption{$Ta$}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering\Tb
\caption{$Tb$}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{15pt}
\vspace{15pt}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering\Tc
\caption{$Tc$}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

There is one little problem I cannot solve. The command:

```
\path[dashed,<->](n1)edge [bend right=45]  node[above left]{reduction}(n2);
```

produces a line that is touching the bottom node, and this is a little annoying.

[image]

I tried different approaches but nothing seemed to work. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: It works fine for me. You might be using an old (i.e. older than 2.1) version of TikZ/PGF. You can check this by inserting `\pgfversion` after `\begin{document}` in your file. Also note that it is helpful if you make your code examples full, compilable documents starting from `\documentclass` so people who want to try out the code don't have to write the preamble themselves and guess at packages you might be loading.

Comment: Please always add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. This means with the preamble and `document` environment. Do you have some global `tikz` style settings? I also don't get the result. The solid lines e.g. from `q(x)` to `~p(x)` is much shorter when I compile the above code.

Comment: @jake: \pgfversion returned 2.10... i will edit my post

Comment: @Nagi The problem is caused by the `tikz-qtree` package.  If you aren't using its methods for inputting trees, you shouldn't load it. (Another reason to make a minimal working example.)

Comment: @Alan: Wow, you sure know your tree packages, to be able to recognise this error without a full MWE.

Comment: @Alan: thank you, fixed it perfectly. i am such a noob... plz post you comment as an answer...

Comment: @Jake Trees is what I do. :-) (Or at least how I represent what I do.)  But I suspect that when Nagi unloads the package, he won't like the result, since other than the placement of the dotted line, the version of the tree with `tikz-qtree` loaded is much nicer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `tikz-qtree` package. If you aren't using its methods for inputting trees, you shouldn't load it. (Another reason to make a minimal working example.)

However, because of the way `tikz-qtree` draws its trees, you might prefer the tree to look that way, in which case Martin's solution will solve the problem.  Here's a comparison of the same tree with `tikz-qtree` loaded and not loaded: (The one with `tikz-qtree` uses the `shorten` solution on the path.)

**Without `tikz-qtree`**

[image: tree without tikz-qtree loaded]

**With `tikz-qtree`**

[image: tree with tikz-qtree loaded]

Comment: i flagged this as the right answer because it is, but i am going to use Martin Scharrer's answer because like you said, it is much nicer with tikz-qtree...

Answer (score 21):

You could use `shorten >=<length>` to shorten the arrow a little bit:

```
\path[dashed,<->,shorten >=5pt](n1)edge [bend right=45]  node[above left]{reduction}(n2);
```

There is also `shorten <` for the other end.

Comment: Not `<`, but `<=` (it's a little ambiguous)